# How to make a listview representing more than one subcategory

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a small problem that I don´t know how to solve. I want to represent some information on a listview, the thing is that this info is divided into several lists. Each one of these lists should have a header and category names (for more details see the image). I have tried with grouping but it doesn´t allow me to do what I need. It would be great if someone could point me out in the right direction on this one.

[Image of listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlndx.png)

Comment: you are going to have a very difficult time rendering that with a ListView.   You may be able to pull it off using a Grid or a third party datagrid

Comment: I´m open to any solution, do you know some third party datagrid that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Use a grouped listview with different cell template.

Comment: Hey Jack Hua I was able to do this with your suggestion. It was not the most elegant solution but it's functional. The listviews are not made for these kind of lists I guess.